# Nuxt App deployed to Heroku doesn't find sass-loader

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js, sass-loader

I'm trying to deploy a Nuxt SPA app to Heroku.
Locally everything works fine, but when I deploy to Heroku it gives me an application error with the info to check my heroku logs:

```
2019-10-11T02:49:50.897584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-11T02:49:54.670233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-10-11T02:49:56.590749+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-11T02:49:56.590769+00:00 app[web.1]: > sol37.web@1.0.0 start /app
2019-10-11T02:49:56.59077+00:00 app[web.1]: > nuxt start
2019-10-11T02:49:56.590772+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-11T02:49:57.167804+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ Listening on: http://localhost:49791/ 2019-10-11T02:50:02.00478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.149207054.9b940788-6a37-40a9-82de-b19b3519e60c sample#memory_total=55.14MB sample#memory_rss=55.14MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=14487pages sample#memory_pgpgout=1392pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2019-10-11T02:50:23.81059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.149207054.9b940788-6a37-40a9-82de-b19b3519e60c sample#memory_total=55.14MB sample#memory_rss=55.14MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=14487pages sample#memory_pgpgout=1392pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2019-10-11T02:50:45.744385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.149207054.9b940788-6a37-40a9-82de-b19b3519e60c sample#load_avg_1m=0.00
2019-10-11T02:50:45.762243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.149207054.9b940788-6a37-40a9-82de-b19b3519e60c sample#memory_total=55.14MB sample#memory_rss=55.14MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=14487pages sample#memory_pgpgout=1392pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2019-10-11T02:50:54.906637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I checked if I set the port somewhere manually, but I'm not doing that anywhere in the project.
Without more information, i tried to build the app on heroku directly.
("heroku run bash" and "npm run build") which gave me the following error.

```
ERROR in ./pages/index.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in '/app'
```

and 7 more of those errors all concerning sass-loader.

not sure if "npm run build" works over heroku bash, but at least it gave me some information.
I have another nuxt project that i run on the same heroku instance which works without a problem.
I tried to check what the differences are and i found that it used a lower sass-loader version, which i downgraded on my current project but it's still not working.

After that I tried to run "npm run start" which is what Heroku runs upon deployment. this gave me first an error with nuxtjs/style-ressource, which i realized i don't utilize right now, so i removed that. After that it ran without any issues, but i couldn't get it to show up in the browser.

Does anyone have any idea what else I could try?

Thanks in Advance
Carlo

Comment: Ok, too stupid to read up on things apparently found this in the nuxt docu, that I probably did last time and completely forgot :D

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/heroku-deployment/

Comment: What did you do ? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @VojislavSibinovic since the error is the classic R10 on Heroku, I will guess he simply forgot to set the HOST constant to 0.0.0.0, you can do it in the comand shell by typing heroku config:set HOST=0.0.0.0 or simply go to your Heroku app settings and create a new config var named HOST and add the value 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @VojislavSibinovic, sorry I haven't seen your reply, i'm usually not logged in to SO. but as ChristianHdz mentioned it was the HOST that I didn't set properly.